# Capture 'output_format' from rmarkdown::render as variable

Tags: r, knitr, r-markdown

I am using RStudio with `knitr`, etc, to make reproducible reports, and want to have the best versions I can for both Word documents and PDF - I prefer working with LaTeX, but the end-users tend to prefer the flexibility of editable Word documents.

I have written a `ifelse` statement that essentially says 'if this is `render`ed as a word document, create a `kable` table in markdown, else create the `kable` table in LaTeX and then manipulate to make the table look better (shaded rows, etc)'.

I don't understand how the `rmarkdown::render`ing process works to capture the `output_format`, but is there a way to store this as a variable and use in the `ifelse` statement?

A minimal example would be to save this code as `test.Rmd`:

```
format <- output_format #(somehow captured as a variable)

printTable <- function(data = df, format = format){

if (format %in% 'pdf_document') {

    # create nice latex table

} else {

    # create markdown table

}
}
```

Then, when running this code:

```
rmarkdown::render(input = "test.Rmd", output_format = c("word_document", "pdf_document"))
```

the different versions of the report would have the correct tables included.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can access the output format via `knitr::opts_knit$get("rmarkdown.pandoc.to")`. This will return a string with the target output format. Here's an example:

````
---
title: "Untitled"
output: html_document
---

```{r}
library(knitr)
opts_knit$get("rmarkdown.pandoc.to")
```
````

This returns "html" for html_document, "docx" for word_document, and "latex" for pdf_document.